# How do I create React drop down forms that dynamically updates the list of options?

Tags: reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to create two drop down option forms in React, with the options being numbers 0-6, except that the sum of the two options cannot exceed 6. Therefore,  if the 5 is chosen for the first drop down box, the second drop down will only display options 0 and 1 to choose from. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save each selection in state, and render the list of available numbers based on what has already been selected in the other input.

State in the constructor could look something like:

```
this.state = {selectionA: 0, selectionB: 0, availableSelections: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]};
```

Whenever a selection is made, set the corresponding selectionA or selectionB using `setState` in an event handler. See the link below for an example in the react docs.

In the render function, make the list of available number using the filter function:

```
const {selectionA, selectionB, availableSelections} = this.state;
const optionsA = availableSelections.filter((num) => (selectionB + num) < 6);
const optionsB = availableSelections.filter((num) => (selectionA + num) < 6);
```

Assuming you are using the `select tag` described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag, display the options using map

```
<label>
  Pick your first number:
  <select value={selectionA} onChange={this.handleChangeA}>
    {optionsA.map((num) => (
      <option value={num}>{num}</option>
    )}
  </select>
</label>
... then the same for selectionB
```

Note, I have not tested this. You might run into issues regarding the state being number type, and forms wanting things in string type, so you might have to do some converting with `parseInt` and `toString`. I hope this helps to get you started!

---

Here is a whole working example building on the FlavorForm example in the react link:

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectionA: 0, selectionB: 0, availableSelections: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]};

    this.handleChangeA = this.handleChangeA.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeB = this.handleChangeB.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeA(event) {
    this.setState({selectionA: parseInt(event.target.value)});
  }

  handleChangeB(event) {
    this.setState({selectionB: parseInt(event.target.value)});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your Sum is: ' + (parseInt(this.state.selectionA) + parseInt(this.state.selectionB)));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const {selectionA, selectionB, availableSelections} = this.state;
    const optionsA = availableSelections.filter((num) => (parseInt(selectionB) + num) <= 6);
    const optionsB = availableSelections.filter((num) => (parseInt(selectionA) + num) <= 6);

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your first number:
          <select value={selectionA.toString()} onChange={this.handleChangeA}>
            {optionsA.map((num) => (
               <option key={num} value={num.toString()}>{num}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          Pick your second number:
          <select value={selectionB.toString()} onChange={this.handleChangeB}>
            {optionsB.map((num) => (
               <option key={num} value={num.toString()}>{num}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FlavorForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When a number is selected, the state will be set for selectionA or selectionB. This will force a re-render which will update the filtered optionsA and optionsB based on the new state.